# How do I find the github repo connected to a heroku instance?

Tags: git, heroku, github

I've been asked to help out on a project where the developer has disappeared and left little to no documentation on the project with him.

"The project is hosted on heroku and the version control system is GitHub" is all the product owner could tell me. He's added me to the heroku instance so I have access to that, but he doesn't know where the code is on GitHub.

***Question:* Is there a way of finding out what the GitHub repository that is connected to a Heroku instance is, using just the information we have in Heroku?**

*Note:* I do see commit hashes in the 'Activity' tab in heroku, but have no access to the diffs.
[image: heroku-activity-tab]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how everything is configured, this may be difficult. There is no inherent dependency between Heroku and GitHub, and it is entirely possible that Heroku has no idea that the code lives on GitHub.

For example, the only "connection" between Heroku and GitHub might be the other developer's local environment, where two remotes are configured:

```
[GitHub] ---.
             \
              }--- [Local dev environment]
             /
[Heroku] ---'
```

### Heroku / GitHub integration

It is also possible that Heroku *does* know about GitHub. There is an optional integration between the two.

1. Log into Heroku and select the application in question.
2. Click on the **Deploy** tab.
3. Click the **GitHub** button.
4. Near the bottom of the page, you should see a **Connect to GitHub** section.

   This will either have instructions for connecting the application to GitHub (in which case the integration doesn't exist) or will show that it is **Connected to** a particular `user/repository` (in which case you have your answer).

### Workaround

If the application isn't connected to a GitHub repository your choices are limited.

It would be better to find the original repository (possibly by getting in touch with the previous developer, or through some sleuthing), but Heroku does provide a feature that could be useful here.

Use [`heroku git:clone -a <app-name>`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app) to clone the repository directly from Heroku. Note that

> Heroku provides the git service primarily for deployment, and the ability to clone from it is offered as a convenience. We strongly recommend you store your code in another git repository such as GitHub and treat that as canonical.

I must emphasise that this should *not* become your regular workflow. In your position I would immediately push this code to my cloud repository provider of choice and use that as the new primary code repository.

If you later discover the original repository it will be interesting to compare your new one to the old one. For example, there may be feature branches on the old repository that wouldn't get captured with the workaround.

This will be even more important if the other developer ever comes back; you will probably want to share the same primary repository.

Comment: This is very useful @Chris, thank you. Unfortunately the project falls into the second category and doesn't appear to be connected to a GH repo. I'll leave the question open just in case anyone else has any ideas, but thanks again!